# Symfony 1.4 won't report exceptions but retunrs a blank/empty screen, how to fix it?

Tags: php, exception, symfony-1.4

When an exception happends, Symfony 1.4 framework just shows a white / empty screen, no output at all. I'm in dev mode. The `log/frontend_dev.log` does log the exception (but not, when it happens in ajax action), but that way it wont help much.

I know it's not too much, but is there any way to fix this? It kinda makes developing impossible

P.S. Yes, next project will be in 2.2

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony/web/index.php (or maybe dev_index.php in 1.4) you can add the following code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with SF1.4, I use it still for personal projects and I've seen it used in heavily trafficked production environments.

Check your error log, as the exception is being logged there. If you don't know where it is you can do this from cli:

```
$-> php -i | fgrep -w error_log
```

By default it logs to /var/log/messages (syslog)

Comment: sadly this wont help me out. In any other applications exceptions works well. Btw yes, it does log that too

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your OP stated you had a white screen, which means a fatal occurred, but is not displayed visually due to error reporting settings. If you parse your error_log you should see the error, if you post that error as an update to your OP I can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

when white screen appear, right click anywhere in the screen and select view page source. Hopefully you will find your error message there. Just carefully see the page source.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem and I resolve this problem buy running below command.Basically it was cache and log folder permission problem.Go into symfony folder and run these commands

```
chmod 777 cache/ log/ -R
php symfony cc
```